# getTaskManager().getTask() in Glympse EnRoute API returning 0

Tags: ios, api, glympse, enroute

I am using EnRoute Api and Glympse server to store tasks for agents for my application. I am able to log in with credentials. However, when I am trying to show all the tasks on my table view cells using this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return(EnRouteWrapper.instance.manager()?.getTaskManager().getTasks()!.count())!
}
```

It does not give me cells and I checked in the console using print statement, it gives GlyArray which is 0. My tasks for users are visible on their EnRoute app on the play store.

I tried this also:

```
print((EnRouteWrapper.instance.manager()?.getTaskManager().getTasks()!.description.count)!)
```

This statement gives me 26, whereas there are only three tasks in my Glympse console.

I want to count those three so that I can show the data in the tableView cell.

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance